# AsynTask background or not

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I got a question.
In my inner class `chargeAdapterAsync`, i got `mDataModel`

```
class chargeAdapterAsync extends AsyncTask< String, String, String >
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( String... action )
    {
        mImageLoader = ImageLoaderFactory.create( context );
        // set up data
        mDataModel = new WhaskListDataModel( context, 10 );
        mAdapter = new PagedListViewDataAdapter< UserWhasks >( );
        mAdapter.setViewHolderClass( this, WhaskListItemViewHolder.class, mImageLoader );
        mAdapter.setListPageInfo( mDataModel.getListPageInfo( ) );

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( String o )
    {
        super.onPostExecute( o );
        mListView.setAdapter( mAdapter );
    }
}
```

when I go in my `WhaskListDataModel`:

```
public class WhaskListDataModel extends PagedListDataModel<UserWhasks> {

    private Context activity;
    private ListWhasksPagination listWhasksPagination;

    public WhaskListDataModel(Context activity, int numPerPage) {
        mListPageInfo = new ListPageInfo<UserWhasks>(numPerPage);
        this.activity = activity;
        listWhasksPagination = new ListWhasksPagination(activity, numPerPage);
    }

    public void prependItem(UserWhasks item) {
        WhaskListDataEvent data = new WhaskListDataEvent();
        Arra
```

then I got `ListWhasksPagination` class, and when I go in, I got:

```
public ListWhasksPagination(Context activity, int limitArr) {
    currentList = new ArrayList<>();
    completeList = new ArrayList<>();
    completeList = getWhasksResult(activity);
    this.limitArr = limitArr;
    firtItem = -1;
    lastItem = 0;
}

private ArrayList<UserWhasks> getWhasksResult(Context activity){
    ArrayList<UserWhasks> sortedWhasks = new ArrayList<>();
    magnetClient = MagnetMobileClient.getInstance(activity);
    try {
        controllerFactory = new UserFactory(magnetClient);
        user = controllerFactory.obtainInstance();
        Call<WhasksPostsResult> callObject = user.getWhasks(
                SharedPreference.ID,
                SharedPreference.AUTHORIZATION, null);
        WhasksPostsResult result = callObject.get();
        for(WhasksResult whask : result.getWhasks()) {
            sortedWhasks.add(new UserWhasks(whask));
        }
        Collections.sort(sortedWhasks, Collections.reverseOrder());
        return sortedWhasks;
    } catch (SchemaException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.LOG_TAG, "can't get userController", e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.LOG_TAG, "failed to execute getUser", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(Constant.LOG_TAG, "getUser interrupted", e);
    }
    return sortedWhasks;
}
```

and in this last class in `getWhaskResult`, i get back some elements, and I'm wondering, is the `getWhaskResult` method or even the class `ListWhaskPagination` is also in the background or not :/

Comment: difficult to understand what is your problem. Please explain it more clearly or with some sample code

Comment: Hard to undestrand your question. But every thing you do in doInBackground method of an AsyncTask is run in a pool of background threads/

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, the code that executes in background is in `doInBackground` method. Other code is not.

So in `doInBackground` you are `mDataModel = new WhaskListDataModel( context, 10 );`, which calls `getWhaskResult`. So `getWhaskResult` will be executed in background

Answer (score 0):

Yes getWhaskResult　executes in background as it is called from doInBackground